# Expansion of universe. Acceleration and observations at different times and distances

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, acceleration, universe, space-expansion

Although I can follow the maths behind I cannot visualise the acceleration of expansion. This should be due to the form of Hubble flow, as I am not a ant on a balloon. Do not attack me on (mis)use of analogy. Say the stretching of a rubber band with marks on it (the comoving coordinates) is perfect to see expansion of space at work. However, how shall I pull one end of the rubber to get accelerated expansion (stretching is more precise probably) BUT a decreasing Hubble factor?

I am really considering to get a stretchable ribbon because I have hard time to see how shall I pull it.

I hope this is not too silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually very easy to understand. The Hubble parameter is not $\dot{a}$ (where $a$ is the scale factor) but $\dot{a}/a$.

So let's look at your ribbon. Let's say that his length is $L$ and it grows with speed $v=\dot{L}$. The "Hubble parameter" is then $H=v/L$ i.e. not how much ribbon grows relative to the current length. So instead of thinking like "In one second the ribbon becomes 1 cm longer" you should think like "In one second the ribbon becomes 1% longer".

Let's assume that the ribbon stretches with constant speed $v=\mathrm{const}$. But as $L$ increases this becomes less and less proportionally to the total length i.e. $H$ decreases.

If we want $H$ constant we have to keep the ratio $v/L$ the same. Therefore absolute speed should grow faster and faster. To get this you need to have exponential growth $L=L_0 e^{Ht}$. This corresponds to the universe with no matter and only cosmological constant, so-called de Sitter spacetime.

Comment: Yes .indeed L grow faster but not enough. I get it but it is somehow hard to have the feeling of it. Accept after some more time in case of multiple answer. +1